# Best choice of recommenders for PhD admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

**Background**
I am an EE **undergraduate** student intending to apply for a **PhD** program in **computer science** (for Fall 2018), with a focus on the **top 10** universities in this field (mostly in **the US**). I am in a bit of a dilemma with respect to the optimal choice of recommenders. Typical PhD program admissions in CS require three recommendations.
This summer, I worked with **three** professors on a **single** project (Professor X, Y, Z). Since I was directly under their guidance and did a decent job, I'd expect a strong recommendation from each of them. **Two** of them (Professor X, Y) are alumni of universities I intend to apply to and are well-established researchers in the field.
Additionally, I've also worked (and am still working) with (Professor A) in my home university, who recently finished her post-doc at a renowned school abroad. I expect a strong recommendation from her (assuming the on-going work goes well).
In my home university I have a **couple** of other options. I did quite well in (Professor B)'s undergraduate and follow-up graduate course. I worked with (Professor C) on two undergraduate course projects, but these were in EE (electrical engineering) and there wasn't much interaction with C over the semester.

**In a nutshell**, A, X, Y, Z are computer scientists in the field I intend to apply. They are likely to be known to the admission committee. B is a computer scientist in a different field of research. C is a EE researcher. A, B, C, Z are young researchers whereas X, Y are more well-established.

**Question**
I definitely intend to take one recommendation from A. Is it advisable to take the other two recommendations from X and Y (or Z)? The issue is that I was jointly advised by them on the same project and I fear that they might highlight similar things. I don't expect the recommendations from B or C to be as strong as A, X, Y or Z. Should I prefer A, X, Y or A, (X or Y) and (B or C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easy answer is to prefer recommendation from people you did research with over the ones who only taught classes you were taking.

Taking recommendation from two people who advised you on the same project won't necessarily result in the same recommendation letter with two different names. Your supervisors are different people likely to have different approaches to research. They will see different positives (or negatives) in your work and will put the ones they consider more relevant in your recommendation letters. The letters might come out as complementary to each other.

As a general rule, a good recommendation will be more useful if it's coming from people in the field you want to apply.

I don't know if recommendations coming from alumni of your future graduate school would hold more weight than the ones from other people. I think it may depend on the relationship these professors have with people in the department. If they were great students there, I'd take their recommendations.

If you've done great work under X, Y or Z supervision, any two recommendations from them would look good.